# Extracting object from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a sample script from Webdriver.io website which is something like this (modified for testing)

```js
const { remote } = require('webdriverio');
var assert = require('assert');

;(async () => {
        const browser = await multiremote({
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
            },
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            }
    })
    await browser.url('https://www.google.com');
    var title = await browser.getTitle();
    assert.equal(title, 'Google');
    await browser.deleteSession()
})()
```

I need to extract `capabilities.browserName` from this, and so far I'm able to extract them like this

```js
var browsers = str.match(/\scapabilities\s*?:\s*?\{[^{}]+\}/gi); // find capabilities
console.log(browsers.length); // check length
for(let i=0; i < browsers.length; i++){
    let b = browsers[i].replace(/\scapabilities\s*?:\s*?/, '') // remove capabilities: part
                       .replace(/'/g, '"' ) // convert single quote to double quote
                       .replace(/\s/g, '') // remove spaces, new lines, tabs etc.
                       .replace(/(\w+:)|(\w+ :)/g, function(matchedStr) { // wrap words in double quote as keys are not wrapped
                            return '"' + matchedStr.substring(0, matchedStr.length - 1) + '":';
                          });

    let browser = JSON.parse(b); // parse the string to convert to object
    console.log(browser.browserName); // Success !!!
}
```

This works fine but some time capabilities can have nested properties like

```js
capabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   proxy: {
     proxyType: 'PAC',
     proxyAutoconfigUrl: 'http://localhost:8888',
   }
},
```

This breaks my code and only returns me one browser `firefox`. `await multiremote()` can be `await remote()` as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the first input script defines an object that only has one browserName, since an object cannot have duplicate keys, and `capabilities` is duplicate in that object literal.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that there are no parentheses in the object literal that is passed to `remote` or `multiremote`, then we could capture that object literal as a whole by matching all that is between the parentheses of the function call.

I would not go through the effort of trying to convert JavaScript object literal syntax to JSON. Instead, we can assume that `browserName` properties imply they occur in `capabilities` objects, and just match the `browserName` key and value that follows (in single quotes).

Here is how that works out:

```js
const str = `const { remote } = require('webdriverio');
var assert = require('assert');

;(async () => {
    const browser = await multiremote({
        myChromeBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome'
            }
        },
        myFirefoxBrowser: {
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            }
        }
    })
    await browser.url('https://www.google.com');
    var title = await browser.getTitle();
    assert.equal(title, 'Google');
    await browser.deleteSession()
})()`;

               // find object literal, assuming it has no parentheses:
const browsers = str.match(/\bawait\s+(multi)?remote\s*\((.*?)\)/gs)
               // find browserName properties with single quoted string values:
               ?.[0]?.match(/\bbrowserName\s*:\s*'[^']*/g)
               // extract the corresponding values:
               ?.map(m => m.split("'")[1]);
console.log(browsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a quick parser that uses `{` and `}` to check the depth of the nesting. This assumes no `{` characters occur in quotes, keys aren't quoted, and values are quoted with single quotes, so it's not designed to handle every edge case, only those you've provided here.

```js
const s = `const { remote } = require('webdriverio');
var assert = require('assert');

;(async () => {
        const browser = await multiremote({
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
            },
            capabilities: {
                browserName: 'firefox'
            },
            capabilities: {
               browserName: 'chrome',
               proxy: {
                 proxyType: 'PAC',
                 proxyAutoconfigUrl: 'http://localhost:8888',
               }
            },
    })
    await browser.url('https://www.google.com');
    var title = await browser.getTitle();
    assert.equal(title, 'Google');
    await browser.deleteSession()
})()`;

const results = [];
const re = /\bcapabilities: *{/g;

for (let match; match = re.exec(s);) {
  let braces = 0, i = match.index;
  
  for (; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === "{") {
      braces++;
    }
    else if (s[i] === "}") {
      if (--braces <= 0) {
        i++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  results.push(
    s.slice(match.index, i)
     .match(/\bbrowserName: *'([^']*)'/)[1]
  );
}

console.log(results);
```

Also, bear in mind your original string has two `capabilities` keys, so only the second would exist in the object in memory. I assume this is an artifact of adapting the source string to SO, so I didn't bother adjusting that here and simply slapped on a third to show the parsing working on the scope of the question.